# Android Studio reference Library

Tags: android, gradle

Hey guys I really got a problem I can't solve.

I'm developing an Android application which needs a library I wrote for myself (model.jar). I added it to Android Studio and everything was fine. 
On some point it just didn't work anymore so I did everything I could do:

- removed the not working library from my project
- put the library to the projects /libs directory
- added the libray via Project Structure -> File dependency -> model.jar
- added the jar to the projects .gradle file to compile
- Rebuild Project
- Invalidate Caches and restart
- deleted the projects .iml file and .idea folder and reimported the application
- executed `gradlew clean` and `gradlew assemble` from command line
- edit: I did also a Sync Project with Gradle Files

However none of these worked. It still cannot resolve the objects from the jar and I'm just stuck.

Since I am not allowed to post images directly [I uploaded it into my dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sj6ftzyepdp7px0/jars.PNG?dl=0)

Note that I cannot expand the model.jar as the other libraries that do work.

The build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 21
   buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

   defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.rcsrcs.osiris"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/mina-core-2.0.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.7.jar')
    compile files('libs/model.jar')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

As said before, the mina libraries work fine.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Get rid of the `compile fileTree()` statement, or get rid of all the `compile files()` statements. Those are redundant and may be causing some problems. Beyond that, make sure that `model.jar` looks OK (e.g., unZIP it and confirm that its contents are what you expect).

Comment: I removed the `compile file` statements, but it didn't change anything. mina works but model.jar is still not expandable and not usable. model.jar is definitely fine, because it worked before and is still working in different projects.

Comment: The reason why I asked to you examine this specific copy of `model.jar` is that the IDE doesn't seem to think that it has anything in it, based on your screenshot. Just because the logical library works elsewhere does not mean that this actual JAR file in this actual project is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAR files, being files, can get mangled accidentally from time to time. If your IDE sees the JAR (e.g., it shows up in the list of dependencies in Android Studio), but it does not see *contents* of the JAR, check to make sure that it is a clean copy of the JAR. Ideally, the IDE would be a bit more "in your face" about a broken JAR file...

Comment: I was wondering if you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/d5opg5 . It's not one of those "fix-this-for-me" questions, I promise.